# QGIS action for inserting text in field by hotlink

Tags: qgis, actions

I hope to make a simple action in QGIS, where the field in my layer column "Process" can change from "NULL" to "Finished". I use hotlink to click on the polygon in the layer, where I want the action to be.

I tried to do use type Generic and

```
[%Process%]=substr('Finished',0,10)
```

but this did not work.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the *Type* from `Generic` to `Python`, you could use the following instead:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('Process')
layer.changeAttributeValue([% $id %], idx, 'Finished')
layer.commitChanges()
```

Before you run your action, you will need to select it from the *Layers Panel*

---

Example:

1. Setting up the action:

   [image: Setting action]
2. Running action from **Identify Features** tool by clicking on it:

   [image: Running action]
3. Result - value changed from `Processing` to `Finished`:

   [image: Result]

---

*Also tested successfully with Hotlink.*